# Matrix algebra proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix with $m\ge0$. Prove that if the rank of $A$ equals $n$, $A^TA$ is invertible.

Hint: prove that $A$ and $A^TA$ have the same kernel.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you showed what the hint says? Can you see how to use the hint?

Comment: @Tobias I am not sure how to prove what the hint says. Could you give me an idea how I could show this?

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo It is asked to prove that AtA is invertible, not just At itself.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/199981/9464

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint for how to prove the hint ;)

Suppose $v$ is in the kernel of $A^TA$. This means that $A^TAv = 0$, and so $v^TA^TAv = (Av)\cdot(Av)=0$.

Can you take it from there?

EDIT: More explicit help, as requested.

From above we have that if $v\in\ker A^TA$, then $(Av)\cdot (Av) =0$. This means that $\|Av\|^2 = 0$, which is possible only when $Av = 0$. Therefore $\ker A^TA \subset \ker A$.

The other direction is easy: if $w\in \ker A$, obviously $w\in \ker A^TA$.

Therefore $A$ and $A^TA$ have the same kernel, or more importantly, that their kernels have the same dimension. By the rank-nullity theorem, the kernel of $A$ has dimension $n-n=0$, so the kernel of the square matrix $A^TA$ has dimension 0. This means that it is invertible.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand your steps, but unfortunately I still dont see how to proceed from here. How does this show that they share the same kernel?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very much appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: I have one more question. Why does it follow that AtA is invertible from the fact that the kernel had dimension 0?

Comment: What theorems have you proven about invertible matrices? Usually you show early on that a square matrix is invertible iff it has full rank.